# How to make <li> have a full height background(as big as the navbar)

Tags: html, css

My question is exactly what I have asked in the title. This is what I'm failing at: https://gyazo.com/24f0bef2246e9064b87b4218bbbea909 . As you can see the grey background color only goes around the text "Landing". I have tried pumping up the height of the li but that didnt work. So basically the background color should stretch to the top and bottom of the navbar(#menu).

My navbar:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Landing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Story</a></li>
            <li class="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/afrojack-logo.png" alt="AfroJack"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Procesverslag</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu > li {
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
-webkit-animation: fadein 3s;
/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
-moz-animation: fadein 3s;
/* Firefox < 16 */
-ms-animation: fadein 3s;
/* Internet Explorer */
-o-animation: fadein 3s;
/* Opera < 12.1 */
animation: fadein 3s;
}

#menu > li > a {
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
border: none;
}

#menu > li > a:hover {
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
color: #C1C1C1;
}

#menu > li > a > img {
width: 60px;
margin-top: -30px;
margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Your current code don't have any background color, so it's really hard to know what/why this happen (probably missing more elements/css). Take the time to create a complete example (you can use snippets for that, or http://jsfiddle.net for example) that shows the problem.

Comment: @Dekel Found the solution already.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar https://jsfiddle.net/haoftgb4/ there you go. Stretch the preview part, it's not responsive

Comment: @timgfx Lemme check.

Comment: @timgfx You forgot two things. **1.** It should be `padding: 25px;` with no zeroes. **2.** You forgot `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I forgot to mention I reversed what you've told me xD. With that it still doesnt work :/

Comment: @timgfx Working answer added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot two things when I said.

1. It should be `padding: 25px;` with no zeroes.
2. You forgot `display: inline-block`.

**The Code:**

```css
#menu > li > a {
  padding: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q09jyjgv/**

Or if you want to completely remove the space, like this:

[image: preview]

Remove the `padding` from the UL: **https://jsfiddle.net/3u0h0w8x/**